# If I license my app with GNU GPL3, does that prevent me from selling it on android market?

Tags: android, licensing, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using Google Code to host my application code, its conveniant and the SVN repository means I don't have to worry about backups

When you create a project on there you need to select a license, I chose GNU GPL v3.

By doing so, does that prevent me from selling my application on the Android market place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't prevent you selling it, despite the license you still own the code and can issue it under whatever licenses you so desire. It does mean that anyone can take your code, compile it and install it on their Android without paying you a penny but that's probably a small portion of those who might want a good app.

Comment: As I understand it, if only the code is GPLed that would not affect any claims seller has on the the graphics, the layout and sounds which all are subject to copyright. So the user might be able compile it, but he will have to create his own graphics and sounds, to redistribute it since it would not be subject to fair use.

Comment: @daramarak I think you are confusing copyright and license. Copyright in this instance effectively allows me, as the original author, to determine the license under which my work is distributed. This might be a restrictive license where I do not allow copying or modification of my work. It might be like GPL where there is complete freedom. Remember that GPL is focused on "The Program" not the source itself, all elements making up the program need to be licensed under the GPL or compatible license. As I understand it, you can't create a GPL program with limited license resources.

Comment: you are correct. The license actually states "all copyrightable work". My mistake. I was under the impression that GPL applied for the code and the software made from it, but I guess that was only the motivation for the GPL and not the actual license. Does this actually means that anyone else can compile the program and sell it on Android market too?

Comment: Yes, GPL gives them the freedom to do that but they have to make the source available for free (including any changes they make) under the GPL as well.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It just means no one can distribute your software without including the source or an offer to send the source.

You should really read the license *before* you choose to use it...

Comment: Especially +1 for the part about reading licenses before using them.

Comment: Fully agree, but at the time I was experimenting with some code and just wanted a free repos so didn't care. But yes I accept your point :)

Answer (score 3):

> Many people believe that the spirit of the GNU Project is that you should not charge money for distributing copies of software, or that you should charge as little as possible — just enough to cover the cost. **This is a misunderstanding.**
>
> ...
>
> **Distributing free software is an opportunity to raise funds for development. Don't waste it!**

http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't prevent you from selling your app on the market or anywhere else.
However the source code must be available to everyone who bought it and you cannot prevent copying and modification.

An important thing about GPL is that there are no such thing as "end users" : you have no more rights than your users. For example they can take your app, modify (or not) it and publish it under another name as long as they include the (modified) source code. This is called "forking".

However you still own your code. It means that it you are the only developer, you can change the license of future releases. But keep in mind that switching to something more restrictive can result in forking.

Answer (score 0):

To Wooble's answer I'd like to add that the GPL not only guarantees that people must (offer to) distribute the source code when distributing your program, but also that any *changes* they make must be compatibly licensed if they distribute the changes in compiled or source form. This latter part means that if someone else builds on your work, say by making their own app, they have to share it with the world under the same terms as you do.

Comment: Let's extra clarify this. If they build on his code and make their own app AND they distribute the app, then what you say is true. However, if they build an app for internal company use OR they use it to power a webapp, they are under no obligation to show their modifications. This webapp aspect was one of the issues FSF was dealing with in v3, distribution over a network. This is an area where the GPL begins to lose, well, its GPLness.